# How to forward HTTPS trafic from a GW server to VPS squid CONNECT server?

Tags: linux, proxy, https, squid

Here is what am seeking after:
i have 2 hosts x.x.x.1, x.x.x.2 and gateway y.y.y.y and external VPS squid server z.z.z.z
host x.x.x.1 for example send request to https://website.example
i have website.example IP so I want to intercept this request and send it to squid CONNECT server without breaking ssl certificate
I hope that Question is clear

Answer (score 0):

Set https_proxy on x.x.x.1 and x.x.x.2 to z.z.z.z:3128 (if squid runs on default port).

Comment: I don't want hosts make any thing, i want do it from GW

Comment: then afaik you have to write your own patch for squid.

Comment: my problem is not with squid, my problem is how to forward the request from GW to squid without breaking ssl

Comment: Then what will squid without patch do except throwing an error message to log?

Comment: Why error, i want to use it with CONNECT tunnel

Comment: Because squid doesn't know the destination ip address. Only netfilter knows that ip, so you have to pass this ip from netfilter stack to squid process (kernelspace to userspace plus remote to other machine). Squid hasn't a feature like get ip from external sources for CONNECT, so you have to write a patch.